# Гиперболический арктангенс в C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Нужно вычислить гиперболический арктангенс на промежутке -1 до 1, не включая эти числа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arcth = 0.5 * log((x+1)/(x-1));
```

Пройдитесь циклом. Шаг и исключения сами задайте.

Comment: записывао так, все значение на промежутке равны нулю

Comment: arcth=0.5*log((1+x)/(1-x)) вот такая формула на самом деле! и она тоже не работает

Comment: И как она не работает? Почему-то у меня с точностью до 4х знаков и atanh(x), и эта формула печатает одинаковые значения.

Comment: я не знаю, почему не считает

Comment: double arcth;

Comment: Не соблаговолите ли представить результаты? Вот текст:

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    int main() {
      double x, delta = 0.1;
      for(x = -1.0 + delta; x < 1.0; x+=delta)
        printf("%5.2f %10.4f %10.4f\n", x, atanh(x), 0.5*log((1.0+x)/(1.0-x)));
      return 0;
    }

Answer (score 3):

atanh есть функция в math.h начиная с C99